# Not able to login to ELK stack

Tags: logstash, kibana, elk

I have installed ELK on one of the VM(Ubuntu machine) in Azure Enviroment, i am unable to access it via http://localhost:5601 in a sandbox machine which is in the same environment  how to login to the ELK stuff
do I have to change any configurations for all the stuff installed or provide ip details of the VM(windows) in which i was searching for, instead of localhost mentioned in the .yml files for all the products(logstash,kibana,elastic search)

Please provide me the solution as in how can i access elk from another vm(windows server in same env

i tried changing the ubuntu machine ip in the .yml file and searched with the ubuntu machine ip instead of localhost but still not working, let me know how this can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

You have to set network.host to 0.0.0.0